# html_node case sensitivity with website meta data tags

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to detect the content management system of a number of sites by extracting the `meta name="generator"` tag using the `rvest` package. The code looks something like this:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.example.com"

meta_generator <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("meta[name=generator]") %>%
  html_attr("content") %>% 
  paste(collapse = "")
```

The complexity is that Drupal capitalizes the 'g' in generator thus: `meta name="Generator"`

Whereas Wordpress presents as `meta name="generator"` and so my code above will detect the Wordpress but not Drupal tag in this case.

Is there an easy equivalent to `ignore.case = TRUE` for `rvest`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a comma:

```
meta_generator <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("meta[name=generator],meta[name=Generator]") %>%
  html_attr("content") %>% 
  paste(collapse = "")
```

Comment: Works. Simple solution to an annoying problem. Thanks.